# I use SwiftUI and use animation for Circle(), but when the screen is shown through NavigationLink, the location of the animation is not right

Tags: ios, animation, swiftui

```
    `ZStack() {
            Circle()
                .stroke(Color.yellow, lineWidth: 3)
                .scaleEffect(animationAmount)
                .opacity(Double(2 - animationAmount))
                .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 2).repeatForever(autoreverses: false), value: animationAmount)
                .background(.blue)
            
            Image(poke.imageUrl)
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                .padding()
                .clipShape(Circle())
                .scaleEffect(isAnimating ? 1.2 : 1.0) 
                .rotationEffect(.degrees(isAnimating ? 10 : 0))
                .shadow(radius: 8)
                .background(Circle().fill(Color.green))
        }`
```

I wrote the same code as above
When previewed in that view, the circle on the image works normally as I want
However, when you come to View with Image and Circle via NavigationLink from the previous View, the location where the animation of Circle() operates does not match the image

I want to use ZStack to put the image and circle in the same position and the animation of the circle works according to the image position.

`.animation(.easeInOut(duration: 2).repeatForever(autoreverses: false), value: animationAmount)`

The problem is, if you take this cord out, the stroke in the circle is in the desired position

But when I wrote this code, I found that the location of the stroke was at the top of the view

As explained by the code, I want to match the location where the stroke animation of the image and circle works

Is there anyone who can help me

This is translated, if you find it hard to understand please leave a comment thank you

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using a `ZStack`, try showing the yellow circle as an overlay over the `Image`. This way, the size and position of the circle will always correspond to the size and position of the image.

- If the `.scaleEffect` is applied after the green background and the overlay, these will be scaled too.
- The blue background can be applied using another `.background` modifier to the `Image`. To fill all of the screen background, set a frame with `maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity`.
- When you update the flag `isAnimating`, you can either do it `withAnimation`, or you can add an `.animation` modifier to the  `Image`.

```swift
NavigationStack {
    NavigationLink("Show image") {
        Image(poke.imageUrl)
            .resizable()
            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
            .padding()
            .clipShape(Circle())
            .background(Circle().fill(Color.green))
            .overlay {
                Circle()
                    .stroke(Color.yellow, lineWidth: 3)
                    // .scaleEffect(animationAmount)
                    .opacity(Double(2 - animationAmount))
                    .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 2).repeatForever(autoreverses: false), value: animationAmount)
            }
            .scaleEffect(isAnimating ? 1.2 : 1.0) // 이미지 크기 조절
            .rotationEffect(.degrees(isAnimating ? 10 : 0)) // 이미지 회전
            .shadow(radius: 8)
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
            .background(.blue)
            .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 2).repeatForever(autoreverses: false), value: isAnimating)
            .onAppear {
                isAnimating = true
                animationAmount = 2
            }
            .onDisappear {
                isAnimating = false
                animationAmount = 1
            }
    }
}
```

[image: Animation]